# Show the following function has a local minima in $0$:

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics, maxima-minima

Given the function $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as:

$$f(t)=\int_0^t\sin(t\sqrt{1+x^2})dx$$

show $f$ has a local minima in $0$. My question is:
can we show that $f$ has a local minimum in $0$ using its asymptotic behaviour?

Indeed, we can see that $f(t)\sim t\int_0^t\sqrt{1+x^2}dx=g(t)$ when $|t|<1$, thus $f'(t)\sim g'(t)=\int_0^t\sqrt{1+x^2}dx+t\sqrt{1+t^2}$ and we have that $g'(0)=0$, $g'(t)>0$ when $t>0$ and $g'(t)<0$ when $t<0$ (provided we restrain ourselves at $|t|<1$) hence concluding the exercise.

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus comes to mind. This might answer the original question but not your question.

Comment: I agree, but can we differentiate without any problem although the variable appears both  on the interval of integration and the integrand function?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to compute the derivative since the sign of $f(t)$ can be easily determined for small $t$:

- $f(0) = 0$.
- For $0 < t < 1$ and $0 \le x \le t$ is
  $$
   0 < t\sqrt{1+x^2} \le \sqrt 2 \implies \sin(t\sqrt{1+x^2}) > 0
  $$
  and therefore $f(t) > 0$.
- Similarly, $f(t) > 0$ for $-1 < t < 0$.

It follows that $f$ has a local minimum at $t=0$.

Comment: Indeed, you are right thanks! It does simplify my computations, but in any case is it safe to say that asymptotic analysis is a valuable choice?

Comment: In general, $f(t) \sim g(t)$ does not imply that $f'(t) \sim g'(t)$. So much more work would be needed to justify that conclusion in your case.